# Crashlytics NDK 2.0.1 doesn't log native crashes

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm trying to migrate Crashlytics `2.6.7 -> 2.8.0` and Crashlytics NDK `1.1.6 -> 2.0.1`

But I encountered the issue that each time my app is restarted after native crash, Crashlytics writes to logcat something like this:

> 12-18 19:48:33.499 11678-11717/? W/CrashlyticsCore: No minidump data found in directory /data/data/com.example.app/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-ndk/native/1513601249792

and I don't see any info about the crash in my dashboard. At the same time, Java crashes are successfully logged and appear in the dashboard.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

The C++ code I'm using for test (there is SIGSEGV should be thrown):

```
if(_stream)
    {
        delete _stream;
        _stream->close();
        _stream=NULL;
    }
```

What I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Does this happen on all devices that you're testing on or only a particular device?

Comment: The same issue here, and no solutions found yet. All my tested devices are the same.

Comment: Did you  find solution? Seems I have same issue. all native crashes disappears

Comment: Are you calling `Fabric.with()` using `new CrashlyticsNdk()`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467751/332798